# How do I deploy an existing nodejs app on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure

I've written a MEAN stack application locally on my machine, and now I want to put it up on Azure, somehow.

My application code is stored and managed in github.

How do I deploy the app in Azure?

Comment: You can deploy a MEAN application to Azure Websites;  The main issue will be that Azure does not host Mongo instances natively, so if your application uses the M in your MEAN application, you'll either have to find another host for that portion, or self host the application in an Azure Virtual Machine.

Comment: simplest way to get started could be to create a azure vm from azure management console and run the app in the VM.

Answer (score 3):

It's as easy as creating a website using the portal. Had no problems with SQLite or Redis so mongoDb should be ok. You can also use MongoLab.

***Web APP***:

1. Sign in to manage.windowsazure.com
2. Click New -> Compute -> Web APP -> Quick Create -> Type a name, Create a service plan, Select Region
3. Select your newly created Web APP -> Navigate to Dashboard -> Under Quick Glance Select Set up development from source control
4. Select Github -> type in credentials
5. Wait for deployment

***MongoLab***:

1. Navigate to Marketplace, Click New and Select MongoLab
2. Type Name, Select Service Tier
3. Get the connection string
4. Navigate to your Web APP, Select Configure Tab, Scroll to Connection Strings, Type the Key/Value pair for your db connection

**References**:

[Create a Node.js site deploy from GitHub](http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/videos/create-a-nodejs-site-deploy-from-github/)

[Build and deploy a Node.js web app in Azure App Service](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac.md)

[Building Web Apps on the MEAN Stack with OData in Microsoft Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn857363.aspx)

[Deploy a MEAN app on Azure](http://adam-back.azurewebsites.net/deploy-a-mean-app-on-azure/)